# How to know if a 500 error is raised in DRF exception handler?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a custom exception handler in django rest. I want to determine if incoming exception is a 500 exception or related to 500 exceptions.

```py
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

    return response
```

The problem is response status code is determined only when exception is related to serializer or a explicit response with 500 error code is raised. When I try to raise a python exception like `ValueError`, the `response` is None. And there is no way to know if exception is 500 or should be 500.

I need to know if exception is a 500 error in my custom exception handler. What should I do?

Comment: This is handled automatically for you. If `custom_exception_handler` returns `None`, then a 500 will be used. More information [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling): `The exception handler function should either return a Response object, or return None if the exception cannot be handled. If the handler returns None then the exception will be re-raised and Django will return a standard HTTP 500 'server error' response.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `APIException.status_code` member if you are curious.  It will not be present when the exception is not raised by DRF.

```py
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    error_status = getattr(exc, "status_code", None)
    if error_status is None:
        # error is not a drf error
    elif error_status >= 500 and error_status <600:
       ...
    elif error_status >= 400:
       ...
```

If you look in the DRF source code you will see the attribute:

- Base [`APIException`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L104) is a 500
- The [`ValidationError`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L144) is a 400

```py
class ValidationError(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = _('Invalid input.')
```